# Flutter - PageView - Don't change page if the user still touches the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

How to update the `PageView` to trigger `onPageChange` only on specific conditions?

**Here, I don't want to change the current page if the user is still touching the screen. Apart from that, everything should remain the same (ballistic scroll simulation, page limits)**

It seems it has to deal with the `ScrollPhysics` object attached to `PageView`, but I don't know how to correctly *extends* it.

Let me know if you need some code, but the question is very general and can refer to any `PageView`, so you should not need any context.

## Minimum Reproductible Example

Here is the translation in *dart* of the text above. Feel free to update this code to make it achieve the objective.

```dart
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: _title, home: MyPageView());
  }
}

class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPageView> createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: PageView.builder(
      onPageChanged: (int index) {
        // TODO: Don't trigger this function if you still touch the screen
        print('onPageChanged index $index, ${controller.page}');
      },
      allowImplicitScrolling: false,
      controller: controller,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        print('Build Sliver');
        return Center(
          child: Text('Page $index'),
        );
      },
    )));
  }
}
```

## Example of a (bad) solution

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(title: _title, home: MyPageView());
  }
}

class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPageView> createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Listener(
        onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
          if (controller.page == null) {
            return;
          }

          if (controller.page! > 0.5) {
            //TODO: update the time so it fits the end of the animation
            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700), () {
              print('Do your custom action onPageChange action here');
            });
          }
        },
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print('Build Sliver');
            return Center(
              child: Text('Page $index'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This solution triggers an action on the next page, **700ms** after the user stops touching the screen.

It does work, but it is a *lousy work*.

1. How to account for different screen sizes? **700ms** is the maximum amount of time to animate between *2* pages on an *iPhone SE*.
2. How to adjust this arbitrary number (**700**), so it varies according to `controller.page` (the closer to the next page, the smaller you have to wait).
3. It doesn't use `onHorizontalDragEnd` or a similar *drag detector*, which can result in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Of course, what would you like? No project is attached to this question; you have all the elements needed to answer the question in my original post. If you need any other information, let me know ☺️

Comment: Consider including full widget that will reproduce the same issue, (not project), you can get idea from 1st comment

Comment: Done, I hope it will help you  Thank you for asking for precisions.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable the scrolling entirely on [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) with `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and detect the scroll left and right on your own with [`GestureDetector`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). The `GestureDetector.onHorizontalDragEnd` will tell which direction the user dragged, to the left or to the right, checking the parameter's [`DragEndDetails`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragEndDetails-class.html) property `primaryVelocity`. If the value is negative the user dragged to the right and is positive if the user dragged to the left.

To change the page manually just use the [`PageController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html) methods `nextPage` and `previousPage`.

Take a look at the screenshot below and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0b83c8a66ac269e11f881ba871164cfa).

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) => (details.primaryVelocity ?? 0) < 0
            ? _pageController.nextPage(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            : _pageController.previousPage(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeInOut),
        child: PageView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _pageController,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 91, 187),
            ),
            Container(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 213, 0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't fit the constraints (I already had a similar solution). With this solution, you break all the pre-existing behaviour (no more natural swipe when you touch the screen, nor any effects when you reach the end of the scrollable content).
I need a solution that feels the same as `PageScrollPhysics`. However, the current page shouldn't change if you still touch the screen (so if you didn't release the *ballistic effect* yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` inside `PageView()` to achieve this kind of behaviour

Comment: As I replied to @lepsch, this doesn't work on its own. However, it may be an excellent first idea to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same solution and built a complex custom gesture controller with drag listeners.

However, your so called bad example seems like the right direction.\

- Why have this `700ms` at all?\
- You already have the `onPointerUp` event, where you can check the current page by using `controller.page.round()`.\
- You can also check that there is a dragging going on at this pointerUp by comparing `controller.page==controller.page.floor()`